# How to calculate the percentage difference for multiple values

Tags: percentage, differences

If I want to calculate the percentage diffidence for two values (v1 and v2), I would use [(v1-v2)/(v1+v2)/2]*100. But I do not know how to do this if I have three or more values (v1,v2, v3...). Not sure if relative standard deviation would work, ie., mean/sd.
Thanks for your help

Comment: For v1=300 and v2=100, your first equation yields 50%, which is a strange result. You should pick one value as the baseline, either v1 is 300% of v2, or v2 is 33% of v1. Here, your equation indicates that v2 is 50% of the average of v1 and v2, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html

Comment: Where 50% comes from?